# Display different logo in home page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i would like to display a different logo in home page (with ACF).

i try with this code but it doesn't work :

```
<?php if(is_home()){ ?>
  <?php $logo = get_field( 'logo', 'option' ); ?>
  <?php if ( $logo ) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="navbar-brand">
     <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="" />
  </a>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
   <?php $logo_footer = get_field( 'logo_footer', 'option' ); ?>
   <?php if ( $logo_footer ) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="navbar-brand">
     <img src="<?php echo $logo_footer['url']; ?>" alt="" />
   </a>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Do you have any tips ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set the homepage in *Settings->Reading->Your homepage*, you'll have to use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`.

More information here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30389

Answer (score 0):

Add This code into your php file where you want to add it.

i hope its working.

```
<?php 
$logo        = get_field( 'logo', 'option' );
$logo_footer = get_field( 'logo_footer', 'option' ); ?>

<?php if ( $logo ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="" />
    </a>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ( $logo_footer ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="<?php echo $logo_footer['url']; ?>" alt="" />
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```